# The accessing of GoogleAnalytics instance

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-play-services

The newer version of `play-services-analytics-impl` in version 18.0.2 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-analytics/18.0.2 causes warnings for the `GoogleAnalytics` instance and methods used. The warning message is

`This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope`

Does anyone know how to fix this problem without suppressing the warning?

[image]